# How to impute missing data using the MICE package in R?

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation, r-mice

I have a dataset about 2000 observations for further analyses. There are 4 variables that have a lot of missing values (percentage of missing is over 50%). I'm trying to use MICE package to impute missing values. Here are my questions:

1. For the final dataset, it contains variables from different dataset previously. Should I use the final dataset to impute the missing values for those variables, or should I use the original dataset (where those 4 variables are from) which has data that are more relevant to those 4 variables?
2. I saw two different codes online:

```
imputed_Data <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
completeData <- complete(imputed_Data,2)
```

Another one:

```
mice(anesimp2, maxit = 5, 
             predictorMatrix = predM, 
             method = meth, print =  FALSE)
```

I'm wondering what the difference is between these two codes and which one I should use. If I use the first code, I'm also wondering what value of the seed I should set in my case.

3. Should I do any preprocessing of the data before running these codes?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The seed just controls the state of random number generator, i.e. to assure reproducibility when tried in another time. For more information about `mice()`, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.11.0/topics/mice)

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I'm still a little confused after looking at the documentation. I'm wondering if the number of 'seed' matters? What would a recommended number to set 'seed' as? 500?

Comment: No specific seed, really. It's there so two people using same dataset, same parameter/argument settings, AND the same seed can get same results when run separately. Only same dataset and parameter/argument settings will yield different result when the seed is different.